# Is it possible to create an Html.DropDownListFor directly from an entity model?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, razor

I have an `IEnumerable` of managers `Model.managers` from this I want to grab the `ID` value which would be `managers.manager_id` and the `text` value which would be `managers.manager_name`  I also have a selected manager value at `Model.SelectedManager` which holds the `manager_id`

What I am trying to do is to stuff all of these values into an `Html.DropDownListFor`

It would need to be a list of all of the `manager_id` and `manager_name` and then automatically select the manager stored at `Model.SelectedManager` is this possible the way I have set it up?

```
public string SelectedManager { get; set; }
public virtual IEnumerable<managements> managers { get; set; }
```

Comment: How does your entity model looks like ? Do you have a view model for your view ?

Comment: I think this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3057873/how-to-write-a-simple-html-dropdownlistfor) would be helpful.

Comment: @Shyju my entity model has a bunch of stuff in it not needed for this specific item but is needed for other parts of the view.  Which is why I wanted to see if I could use it rather than creating a new model from scratch just for a drop down list.  I am using a view model but the only important part of the model was that it was an IEnumerable<management> that contained two items i needed to pull out of it.

Comment: @SamGhatak Sorry I had already read that page and it wasn't helpful, thank you, however.  My needs were creating it from a "non-standard" model that you build into a select list but rather use an entity model that contained the fields I needed.

Comment: Use a view model for your view. Here is a sample http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33398094/asp-mvc-4-request-value-of-dropdownlistfor/33398952#33398952

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you are trying to do the following:

In a service layer (or the controller), you grab a `List` of `SelectListItem` from that managers `IEnumerable`:

```
model.ManagerList = managers.Select(i => new SelectListItem()
               {
                    Text = i.manager_name,
                    Value = i.manager_id.ToString()
               }).ToList());
```

Then, in your view model, you need that SelectedManager for Id and this manager list (of `SelectListItem`):

```
public string SelectedManager { get; set; }
public List<SelectListItem> ManagerList {get; set;}
```

and in your view, you use the `ManagerList` object with the razor helper:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => Model.SelectedManager, Model.ManagerList, 
              new {@class = "form-control input-sm whatever-css-class"})
```

Hope this helps.

Edit: I have always used the selected id as an `int` and not a `string`. So I have not tested it as a `string` actually, and you may want to use it as `int` if `string` does not work.

Comment: Yeah I have to change it to an int but I was ablt to get it to work with a slight modification.  `@Html.DropDownListFor(sl => sl.SelectedManager, new SelectList(Model.managers, "imanagement_co_id", "smanagement_co_name"))` seems to work how I need it to just have to add some classes to it.

Comment: Better modification, since you don't make use of a view item (i.e. SelectList) in your service class ;-) Thumbs up.